# Generate JSON in Rails for JavaScript object parameter

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to generate a chart in my Rails 3 project using the canvasXpress HTML5 / JavaScript library. Their [charting API](http://canvasxpress.org/examples/bar-graphs) uses JSON as one of the parameters in their constructor.  For example:

```
new CanvasXpress('canvas', /* JSON here */);
```

In Rails I'll have a view which renders the chart as part of it's overall output.  So, the JavaScript to create the chart will live in the view.

**I'm not quite sure how to have Rails generate the JSON the JavaScript needs. Should the JSON be generated in a partial view?**

In any case, an example would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route I took in a similar situation was to use two view files (one action) and two requests  to render 1st the page, then 2nd the json/data for a graph. (I am using using the wonderful HighCharts library)

In our case ensuring that the page loaded (with all nav, options etc) before the potentially heavy/long data processing required to provide the json was important. It also gave us the benefit of a view just for the JSON.

Controller:

```
def show
  @graph = Graph.find(id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      @variable_needed_for_html_layout = current_user.graphs
    end

    format.js do 
      @data = @graph.process_data
    end
  end
end
```

The html view(show.html.erb) just renders all the html markup and makes an ajax request(jquery) for the js:

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.getScript('<%= graph_path(@graph, :js) -%>');
    });
  </script>
  <div id="highchart"></div>
```

The js view(show.js.erb) then does all the heavy lifting:

```
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'highchart',
    }
    ...
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Is there something missing from the JQuery getScript evaluation? Mine is blowing up there...

Comment: Never mind. I found out via "rake routes" that Rails 3 doesn't need _show_, so mine worked with report_path instead of report_show_path

Comment: Ha, sorry. Probably should have noted that that was Rails 2.3.

Comment: Actually, I realize that the show was because I had to use a custom route. I change the model name for the example to graph, but it is actually analysis which results in some funky path I can never remember (so I overrode it).

Comment: in html view, we can use  $.getScript('<%= url_for() -%>'); which use the current controller and action name.